# How to iterate in bash environment variable lists?

Tags: bash

It is usual to have directory lists in environment variables, separated with `:` (like `$PATH`, `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and many others).

Is there any tool or standard method to apply a command for each directory in a list?

In my case I need to check if they exists, but many other commands are useful too, so I'm looking for a way to easily iterate on those lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to do it in bash is to separate it to arrays:

```
IFS=: read -ra PATHS <<< "$PATH"

for P in "${PATHS[@]}"; do
    echo "$P"
done
```

Using this form makes any variable assignment within the loop lost:

```
echo "$PATH" | tr : '\n' | while read P; do
    ALL=$ALL:$P
done

echo "$ALL" # => empty string
```

Another a little better way to do it is through:

```
while read P; do
    ALL=$ALL:$P
done <<< "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
```

And starting Bash 3.1, `ALL=$ALL:$P` can further be simplified to `ALL+=$P`.

Comment: your answer covers some unusual syntax, could you explain a bit?

Comment: @RSFalcon7 `bash` is one big unusual syntax hack.

Comment: @sudo_O And worse is awk ;)

Comment: @RSFalcon7 Which part of it do you find unusual?

Comment: @konsolebox ...said nobody ever.

Comment: About parameter expansion: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html. Here strings: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings

Comment: @konsolebox Are we talking about sentiment or syntax? You can not believe that `bash` is nicer/easier to read/write than `awk`?

Comment: @konsolebox the links were enough, thanks! Maybe you should consider insert them in the answer for easily future access

Answer (score 2):

Well the quick thing I'd do would be

```
echo $PATH | tr : '\n' | while read dir; do
  ls "$dir" > /dev/null
done
```

You'll get errors for any components that don't exist (or are not readable). It's not bulletproof, probably.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy your solution passes empty fields to the while, but in normal cases they should be ignored.

Comment: @RSFalcon7 well I said it wasn't bulletproof :)  That could pretty easily be fixed, though I might be just as happy to learn that I've got "holes" in my PATH (or CLASSPATH or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$ echo $PATH | tr : ' ' | xargs -n1 ls -d
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/sbin
ls: cannot access /a/b/c: No such file or directory
```

For just directory that don't exists:

```
$ echo $PATH | tr : ' ' | xargs -n1 ls -d > /dev/null
ls: cannot access /a/b/c: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also take advantage of the positional parameters:

```
IFS=:
set -- $PATH
for dir in "$@"; do
    : do something with "$dir"
done
```

The for loop can also be written more concisely to loop over the positional parameters:

```
for dir; do ...
```

Depending what else you do in your script, you might want to save the current IFS before overwriting it:

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=:
# ...
```